# Java Nice Format Double

Tags: java, string, double

How can I format a double to a string so that it shows all (no limit) decimal places if they are there but not show any trailing 0s?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: Better look at [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) javadoc

Comment: What do you plan to do for doubles whose decimal representation has infinite digits?

Comment: What do you plan to do for doubles whose decimal representation actually has infinite zeroes? :-O

Comment: @yshavit Show it as an approximation. Basically make it human readable but with highest precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double x = ...;
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat();
fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(fmt.format(x));
```

Integer.MAX_VALUE is a silly number, but any sufficiently large number is fine, as you'll see from the setMaximumFractionDigits javadoc:

> Sets the maximum number of digits allowed in the fraction portion of a number. For  formatting numbers other than BigInteger and BigDecimal objects, the lower of newValue and 340 is used. Negative input values are replaced with 0.